# Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I cannot run the following code on my mac (R version 3.6.3, tidyverse version 1.3.0), although it runs on the author’s computer (R version 3.6.0, tidyverse version 1.3.0).

```
    library('tidyverse')


    df <- data.frame(subj_id=c('x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y'),
             set_size=c(4,8,4,8,4,8,4,8),
             condition=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'),
             x=c(1,5,2,8,3,4,1,5))

    slopes <- df %>%
      group_by(subj_id,condition) %>%
      do(model=lm(x~set_size,data=.)) %>%
      tidy(model) %>%
      # we are interested in the slope, i.e., the effect of set size.
      filter(term=="set_size")
```

The error is on line 9 `tidy(model)`, this is the message I get:

```
    Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 

      Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.

      Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.

    In addition: Warning messages:

    1: Data frame tidiers are deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release of broom. 

    2: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

    3: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

    4: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue would be really helpful!

Comment: That last line `filter(term==‘set_size')`. The first quote (right after the double equal sign) is not actually a quote but something else.

Comment: @chiara Are you using the  `broom` package for the `tidy` function ? If so, then `tidy(model) %>%` should be changed to `broom::tidy(model) %>%`. Otherwise your code won't reproduce the error or work, it will just give an error saying it can't find `tidy`.

Answer (score 1):

Most important is the version of `broom` package you are using - looks to be different. Currently a new syntax is recommended/offered for `broom`.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

```r
tidyverse::tidyverse_deps()
#> # A tibble: 23 x 4
#>    package   cran    local   behind
#>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <lgl> 
#>  1 broom     0.7.2   0.7.2   FALSE 
#>  2 dbplyr    2.0.0   2.0.0   FALSE 
#>  3 dplyr     1.0.2   1.0.2   FALSE 
#>  4 forcats   0.5.0   0.5.0   FALSE 
#>  5 ggplot2   3.3.2   3.3.2   FALSE 
#>  6 haven     2.3.1   2.3.1   FALSE 
#>  7 hms       0.5.3   0.5.3   FALSE 
#>  8 httr      1.4.2   1.4.2   FALSE 
#>  9 jsonlite  1.7.2   1.7.2   FALSE 
#> 10 lubridate 1.7.9.2 1.7.9.2 FALSE 
#> # … with 13 more rows

library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(subj_id=c('x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y'),

                 set_size=c(4,8,4,8,4,8,4,8),

                 condition=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'),

                 x=c(1,5,2,8,3,4,1,5))


slopes <- df %>%

  group_by(subj_id,condition) %>%

  do(model=lm(x~set_size,data=.)) %>%

  mutate(tidys = list(broom::tidy(model))) %>%

  unnest(tidys) %>%

  filter(term=="set_size")

slopes
#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#>   subj_id condition model  term     estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <list> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 x       A         <lm>   set_size     1.00       NaN       NaN     NaN
#> 2 x       B         <lm>   set_size     1.50       NaN       NaN     NaN
#> 3 y       A         <lm>   set_size     0.25       NaN       NaN     NaN
#> 4 y       B         <lm>   set_size     1.00       NaN       NaN     NaN
Created on 2020-12-15 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code worked on R version 3.6.3 after making the following changes:

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- data.frame(subj_id=c('x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y'),
         set_size=c(4,8,4,8,4,8,4,8),
         condition=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'),
         x=c(1,5,2,8,3,4,1,5))

slopes <- df %>%
  group_by(subj_id,condition) %>%
  do(model=lm(x~set_size,data=.)) %>%
  mutate(tidys = list(broom::tidy(model))) %>%
  unnest(tidys) %>%
  filter(term=='set_size')
```